# Where is the rendering mode in 2.8?

Tags: rendering

I can't find the option where you can see the 3dviewport as the rendered version. Here's the mode I mean: https://ibb.co/GQtHM9L, the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shortcut from 2.7x was changed from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to switch between Rendered <> Current mode.

In 2.80 press <kbd>Z</kbd> on your keyboard to bring **Shading Pie Menu** and choose desired mode.

[image: sample]

Comment: Great, that worked!